# transition in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to simulate the working of this flip flop. How do I do it for every possible combination of jk, ie. `when j -> 0, k -> 1, Q = 0, Q_n = 0` `when j -> 0, k -> 1, Q = 0, Q_n = 1`.   etc, without creating a new frame every time?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) rectangle (10,7); % Use this to set the dimensions to approximately the page size
    \begin{scope}[shift={({1},{5})}]


        \node(J) at (1,0) {$J$};
        \node[nand gate US,draw,logic gate inputs = nnn,thick] at ($(J)+(2,0)$) (Nand1){};

        \node(K) at ($(J)+(0,-2.5)$) {$K$};
        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn,thick] at ($(K)+(2,0)$) (Nand2) {};

         \onslide<2>{\node(in1) at ($(J)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}} ;};
        \onslide<3>{\node(in1) at ($(K)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}} ;};

        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn, thick,anchor=input 1] at ($(Nand1)+(3,0)$) (Nand3) {};
        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn, thick, anchor = input 3] at ($(Nand2)+(3,0)$) (Nand4) {};

        \draw(J) |- (Nand1.input 2);
        \draw(K) |- (Nand2.input 2);
        \path (J) -- (K) node[midway] (CLK) {$CLK$};

        \draw (Nand1.input 3) --++(180:5mm) coordinate (aux) |- (CLK);
        \draw (CLK-|aux)|- (Nand2.input 1);

        \draw(Nand1.output) |- (Nand3.input 1);
        \draw(Nand2.output) |- (Nand4.input 3);

        \draw (Nand3.output) -- ([xshift=2cm]Nand3.output);
        \draw (Nand4.output) -- ([xshift=2cm]Nand4.output);

        \draw (Nand3.output) --++(0:2cm) node[right](Q) {$Q_n$} coordinate[pos=.25] (aux1) coordinate[pos=.5] (aux2);
        \draw (Nand4.output) --++(0:2cm) node[right] (QN) {$\overline{Q_n}$} coordinate[pos=.25] (aux3) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux4);

        \onslide<2>{\node(out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}} ;};
        \onslide<2>{\node(out2) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}} ;};

        \draw (Nand2.input 3)--(Nand2.input 3-|aux)--++(-90:5mm)-|(aux2);
        \draw (Nand1.input 1)--(Nand1.input 1-|aux)--++(90:5mm)-|(aux4);

        \draw(Nand4.input 1) --++(180:5mm) --++(90:3mm) -- ([yshift = -3mm]aux1) --(aux1);
        \draw(Nand3.input 3) --++(180:5mm) --++(-90:3mm) -- ([yshift = 3mm]aux3) --(aux3);

        \foreach \i in {CLK-|aux,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4}
        \filldraw (\i) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{scope}     
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure I did not get the combinations right, but I think you will find it straightforward to adjust the arguments of `visible on=<...>` to suit your purpose. This nice little trick is from [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino)'s fantastic aobs library (`texdoc aobs`). It also allows you to make certain connections invisible, if needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} %<-added
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) rectangle (10,7); % Use this to set the dimensions to approximately the page size
    \begin{scope}[shift={({1},{5})}]


        \node(J) at (1,0) {$J$};
        \node[nand gate US,draw,logic gate inputs = nnn,thick] at ($(J)+(2,0)$) (Nand1){};

        \node(K) at ($(J)+(0,-2.5)$) {$K$};
        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn,thick] at ($(K)+(2,0)$) (Nand2) {};

        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn, thick,anchor=input 1] at ($(Nand1)+(3,0)$) (Nand3) {};
        \node[nand gate US, draw, logic gate inputs = nnn, thick, anchor = input 3] at ($(Nand2)+(3,0)$) (Nand4) {};

        \draw(J) |- (Nand1.input 2);
        \draw(K) |- (Nand2.input 2);
        \path (J) -- (K) node[midway] (CLK) {$CLK$};

        \draw (Nand1.input 3) --++(180:5mm) coordinate (aux) |- (CLK);
        \draw (CLK-|aux)|- (Nand2.input 1);

        \draw(Nand1.output) |- (Nand3.input 1);
        \draw(Nand2.output) |- (Nand4.input 3);

        \draw (Nand3.output) -- ([xshift=2cm]Nand3.output);
        \draw (Nand4.output) -- ([xshift=2cm]Nand4.output);

        \draw (Nand3.output) --++(0:2cm) node[right](Q) {$Q_n$} coordinate[pos=.25] (aux1) coordinate[pos=.5] (aux2);
        \draw (Nand4.output) --++(0:2cm) node[right] (QN) {$\overline{Q_n}$} coordinate[pos=.25] (aux3) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux4);

        \node[visible on=<{2,3}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{4,5}>](out1) at ($(Q)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
        \node[visible on=<{2,4}>](out2) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{3,5}>](out2) at ($(QN)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
        \node[visible on=<{2,3}>](in1) at ($(J)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{4,5}>](in1) at ($(J)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};
        \node[visible on=<{2,4}>](in1) at ($(K)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{0}}};
        \node[visible on=<{3,5}>](in1) at ($(K)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{1}}};

        \draw (Nand2.input 3)--(Nand2.input 3-|aux)--++(-90:5mm)-|(aux2);
        \draw (Nand1.input 1)--(Nand1.input 1-|aux)--++(90:5mm)-|(aux4);

        \draw(Nand4.input 1) --++(180:5mm) --++(90:3mm) -- ([yshift = -3mm]aux1) --(aux1);
        \draw(Nand3.input 3) --++(180:5mm) --++(-90:3mm) -- ([yshift = 3mm]aux3) --(aux3);

        \foreach \i in {CLK-|aux,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4}
        \filldraw (\i) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{scope}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]